# Assign a string to _ in Swift

Tags: swift

Could somebody explain why the following line:

_ = "hello"

compiles?
It isn't _ used for no-named parameters? Is that assigning a variable "without a name"?

[image]

Comment: `_` can be used for anything you don't want to use. In this case it means you don't want to use the result of some expression.

Comment: I know exactly what _ means in Swift, but the docs mention parameters, not variables assignation.

Answer (score 3):

From [Swift Expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID383)

> Wildcard Expression
>
> A wildcard expression is used to explicitly ignore a value during an assignment. For example, in the following assignment 10 is assigned to x and 20 is ignored:

```
(x, _) = (10, 20)
// x is 10, and 20 is ignored
```